# Ocultar componentes en lugar de desmontarlos

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue3

Hice un componente en vue que se divide en 3 cajas (les digo vistas y la 1 es la vista principal).

```
 ---------
|     | 2 |
|  1  |---|
|     | 3 |
 ---------
```

Inicialmente tengo un objeto que TIENE varias imágenes, y PUEDE TENER vídeos y/o recorridos 360.

En la caja 1, empiezo mostrando la galería de imágenes.

En la caja 2 hay un botón. Si el objeto tiene vídeos, el botón se habilita. Si clickeo en el botón, el vídeo se coloca en la caja 1, y ahora la caja 2 tiene un preview de la galería de imágenes (con un boton que al clickearlo, la vuelve a colocar en la vista 1)

La caja 3 se comporta exactamente igual que la caja 2, pero con recorrido 360 (es un HTML embebido)

> En este momento mi componente se comporta bien y muestra la cosas como debe. Pero ahora quiero agregarle una funcionalidad más y no sé como encararlo.

Yo quiero que, cuando el usuario interactúe con el componente, (por ejemplo recorriendo la galería, o reproduciendo el vídeo, o recorriendo la galería 360) y luego intercambie las vistas, que no se pierda el lugar donde estaba.

Ejemplo: En la galería, yo podría mantener una variable `currentIndex` por ejemplo, y voy verificando en qué posición se encuentra, y al cambiar de vista (a vídeo o 360) y volver a la galería de imágenes, cuando se levante la misma, indicarle que comience por el indice.

Esto lo hice y funcionó, sin embargo no puedo mantener un estado de la galería 360, indefectiblemente se vuelve a iniciar.

Lo que sucede es que, como los `divs` tienen la sentencia v-if, se renderizan condicionalmente y montan o desmontan su contenido.

> Quisiera encontrar una solución (con algo de CSS) que haga que el
> componente cargue las imágenes, los vídeos, la galería 360 solo la
> primera vez que se agreguen respectivamente a la vista 1.
>
> Luego, al ir intercambiando una vista con otra, que no se reemplacen
> los  condicionalmente (como ocurre ahora), sino que se superponga
> una vista principal sobre otra. (de esta manera nunca perdería el
> estado actual del recorrido 360)
>
> Luego, si desmonto el componente, ahí sí deberían desmontarse.
>
> Es posible hacer esto sin desarmar mucho lo que ya hice?

Muchas gracias.

Les dejo el componente:

```
 <template>
  <div class="container-multimedia">
    <div class="col-9 container-principal" v-if="mostrando == 1">
      
      <Galleria :value="arrImgs" :numVisible="5" :activeIndex="activeIndex" :showThumbnails="false" :showItemNavigators="true">
        <template #item="slotProps">
          <img
            class="img-galeria"
            :src="slotProps.item.image"
            :alt="slotProps.item.image"
          />
        </template>
        <template #thumbnail="slotProps">
          <img
            class="img-thumb"
            :src="slotProps.item.thumb"
            :alt="slotProps.item.image"
          />
        </template>
      </Galleria>

    </div>
    <div class="col-9 container-principal" v-else-if="mostrando == 2">
      <galeria-video :videos="arrVids" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 container-principal" v-else-if="mostrando == 3">
      <galeria-360 :keyVid="arr360[0].key" />
    </div>


    <div class="col-3 barra-lateral">
      
      <div class="container-1 multimedia" v-if="mostrando == 1">
        <div v-if="!arrVids.length" class="content-multimedia no-contenido">
          <!-- No hay video. No funciono. -->
          <div class="boton circular">
            <i><icon-base width="25" height="25" icon-name="Videos"><IconVideos /></icon-base></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-else @click="setMostrando(2)" class="content-multimedia normal">
          <!-- CLICK ACA PARA VER LA GALERIA DE VIDEOS -->
          <div class="boton circular">
            <i><icon-base width="25" height="25" icon-name="Videos"><IconVideos /></icon-base></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-1 multimedia" v-else-if="mostrando == 2" @click="setMostrando(1)">
        <!-- CLICK ACA PARA VER LA GALERIA DE IMAGENES -->
          <div class="content-multimedia normal">
            <div class="boton circular">
              <i><icon-base width="25" height="25" icon-name="Fotos"><IconFotos /></icon-base></i>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-1 multimedia" v-else-if="mostrando == 3">
        <div v-if="!arrVids.length" class="content-multimedia no-contenido">
          <!-- No hay video. No funciono. -->
          <div class="boton circular">
            <i><icon-base width="25" height="25" icon-name="Videos"><IconVideos /></icon-base></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-else @click="setMostrando(2)" class="content-multimedia normal">
          <!-- CLICK ACA PARA VER LA GALERIA DE VIDEOS -->
          <div class="boton circular">
            <i><icon-base width="25" height="25" icon-name="Videos"><IconVideos /></icon-base></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- CASOS: 1) Hay fotos, videos y recorrida 360 -->

      <div class="container-2 multimedia" v-if="mostrando == 1">
        <div v-if="!arr360.length" class="content-multimedia no-contenido">
          <!-- No hay recorrido 360. No funciono. -->
          <div class="boton circular">
            <i><icon-base width="30" height="30" icon-name="360º"><Icon360 /></icon-base></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-else @click="setMostrando(3)" class="content-multimedia normal">
          <!-- CLICK ACA PARA VER EL RECORRIDO EN 360 -->
          <div class="boton circular">
            <i><icon-base width="30" height="30" icon-name="360º"><Icon360 /></icon-base></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-2 multimedia" v-if="mostrando == 2" @click="setMostrando(3)">
        <div v-if="!arr360.length" class="content-multimedia no-contenido">
          <!-- No hay recorrido 360. No funciono. -->
          <div class="boton circular">
            <i><icon-base width="30" height="30" icon-name="360º"><Icon360 /></icon-base></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-else @click="setMostrando(3)" class="content-multimedia normal">
          <!-- CLICK ACA PARA VER EL RECORRIDO EN 360 -->
          <div class="boton circular">
            <i><icon-base width="30" height="30" icon-name="360º"><Icon360 /></icon-base></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-2 multimedia" v-if="mostrando == 3" @click="setMostrando(1)">
        <!-- CLICK ACA PARA VER LA GALERIA DE IMAGENES -->
          <div class="content-multimedia normal">
            <div class="boton circular">
              <i><icon-base width="25" height="25" icon-name="Fotos"><IconFotos /></icon-base></i>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <multimedia-full-screen :item="item"/>
</template>

<script>
import IconBase from '@/components/IconBase.vue';
import IconFavoritos from '@/assets/iconos/icono-favorito.vue';
import IconVideos from '@/assets/iconos/icono-videos.vue';
import Icon360 from '@/assets/iconos/icono-360.vue';
import IconFotos from "@/assets/iconos/icono-fotos.vue";
import IconPantallaCompleta from "@/assets/iconos/icono-pantalla-completa.vue";

import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
import Galleria from "primevue/galleria";
import Galeria360 from "../../../Galeria/Galeria360.vue";
import GaleriaVideo from "../../../Galeria/GaleriaVideo.vue";
import { useStore } from 'vuex';
import MultimediaFullScreen from './MultimediaFullScreen.vue';

import $ from 'jquery'
export default {
  components: {
    IconBase,
    IconFavoritos,
    IconVideos, 
    Icon360,
    IconFotos, 
    IconPantallaCompleta,

    Galleria,
    Galeria360,
    GaleriaVideo,
    MultimediaFullScreen,
  },
  props: ["item"],
  setup(props) {
    const item = ref(null);
    item.value = props.item;

    const store = useStore()

    const arrImgs = ref([]);
    const arrVids = ref([]);
    const arr360 = ref([]);

    const activeIndex = ref(0);

    // Variable para saber qué estoy mostrando: 1- imagenes. 2- video. 3-360
    const mostrando = ref(1);

    const setMostrando = (val) => {
      mostrando.value = val;
    };

    // Obtengo imagenes
    item.value.imagenes.map((e) => {
      let obj = {
        image: e.image,
        thumb: e.thumb,
      };
      arrImgs.value.push(obj);
    });

    // Obtengo videos
    if (item.value.videos.length) {
      item.value.videos.map((e) => {
        let obj = {
          id: e.id,
          titulo: e.title,
          descripcion: e.description,
          provider: e.provider,
          key: e.key_video,
          url: e.url,
          player_url: e.player_url,
        };
        if (e.provider == "matterport") {
          arr360.value.push(obj);
        } else if (e.provider == "youtube") {
          arrVids.value.push(obj);
        }
      });
    }

    const abrirGaleriaFullScreen = () => {
      store.dispatch("propiedadPopup/galeriaFullScreenAction", true);
       setTimeout(() => {
        $("#toolbar1").focus();
      }, 100);
    };

    return { arrImgs, arrVids, arr360, mostrando, setMostrando, activeIndex, abrirGaleriaFullScreen, item };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar los [módulos css](https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/features/css-modules.html)

Estos permiten aplicar una clase de css a un elemento de las siguientes formas:

```
<template>
  <!-- equivalente a class="red" -->
  <p :class="$style.red"> 
    Aplicando la clase
  </p>

  <!-- equivalente a class="red" si isRed es true -->
  <!-- en otro caso de vuelve class="" -->
  <p :class="{ [$style.red]: isRed }"> 
    Aplicando de forma condicional
  </p>
  
  <!-- equivalente a usar class="red bold" -->
  <p :class="[$style.red, $style.bold]">
    Por lista
  </p>
</template>

<style module>
.red {
  color: red;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

En tu caso, en vez de usar `v-if` para mostrar tus componentes puedes usar los modulos de css con `display: none;`:

```
<template>  
  <div class="container-multimedia">

    <div class="col-9 container-principal" :class="{[$style.hide]: mostrando !== 1}">
      Galleria ️
      <input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 container-principal" :class="{[$style.hide]: mostrando !== 2}">
      Galleria de video 
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 container-principal" :class="{[$style.hide]: mostrando !== 3}">
      Galleria 360 
    </div>

    <div class="col-3 barra-lateral">
      <div class="container-1 multimedia" v-if="mostrando === 1" @click="setMostrando(2)">
        ver galeria videos 
      </div>
      <div class="container-1 multimedia" v-else-if="mostrando === 2" @click="setMostrando(1)">
        ver galeria de imagenes ️
      </div>
      <div class="container-1 multimedia" v-else-if="mostrando === 3" @click="setMostrando(2)">
        ver galeria de videos 
      </div>

      <div class="container-2 multimedia" v-if="mostrando === 1" @click="setMostrando(3)">
        ver recorrido 360 
      </div>
      <div class="container-2 multimedia" v-if="mostrando === 2" @click="setMostrando(3)">
        ver recorrido 360 
      </div>
      <div class="container-2 multimedia" v-if="mostrando === 3" @click="setMostrando(1)">
        ver galeria de imagenes ️
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from "vue";

export default {
  props: ["item"],
  setup(props) {
    const myItem = ref(props.item);

    // Variable para saber qué estoy mostrando: 1- imagenes. 2- video. 3-360
    const mostrando = ref(1);

    const setMostrando = val => mostrando.value = val;

    return {mostrando, setMostrando, myItem};
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped module>
.hide {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```